# Camel do while loop

Tags: while-loop, apache-camel, do-while

I am trying to use camel dowhile loop.

I have two tables(ex : A,B) in datebase.

The goal is to insert into the data from A to B table by 500 lines for exemple. (The table is too big to use insert into at one time)

Here i want the loop to continue until insert into statement returns "0 rows".

```
        <loop doWhile="true">   
                <!-- Stock last id of table B -->
                <to uri="sql:{{export.table.b.last.fetched.id.query}}?dataSource=testDataSource&amp;outputType=SelectOne" />                     
                <setHeader headerName="last_fetched_id"> 
                    <simple>${body}</simple>                             
                </setHeader>
            <!-- Insert into query by using the last id limit 500 lines -->
            <to uri="sql:{{export.table.a.insert.fetch.query}}?dataSource=testDataSource" /> 
            <simple>${body} != 0</simple>                    
        </loop>
```

I don't know what i do wrong in the codes. I have this error :

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2:
> Attribute 'doWhile' is not allowed to appear in element 'loop'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like xml-validation error. You could double check that you've  defined your loop correctly inside `<route>` and `</route>` tags after `<from>` tag. The xml-validation tests xml against the schemas (`.xsd`) defined in the xml-document.

Also the `<simple>${body} != 0</simple>` should be right after the `<loop doWhile="true">` tag like shown in the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/eips/loop-eip.html#_looping_using_while).

**XML DSL - Documentation:**

- [XML-DSL for Spring](https://camel.apache.org/manual/spring-xml-extensions.html)
- [XML-DSL for OSGi-Blueprint](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/others/blueprint.html)

As for sql queries select operations return body of type `List<Map<String, Object>>` containing query results and number of rows is stored to `CamelSqlRowCount` **header**. With update operations null body is returned and number of rows affected is stored `CamelSqlUpdateCount` **header**,

- [Result of the query](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sql-component.html#_result_of_the_query)
- [Headers](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sql-component.html#sql-component-header-values)

As for the loop you you could try setting the body to the value of `CamelSqlUpdateCount`:

```xml
<setBody>
    <header>CamelSqlUpdateCount</header>
</setBody>
```

Alternatively if you're using direct consumer endpoint you could remove the loop altogether and use recursion instead by just calling the route again at the end until `CamelSqlUpdateCount` is zero.

Comment: I rewrite the code like as below but the problem persist always.
The loop block is well placed in root tag and after from tag.
Do you have any idea what i do wrong here ?




_<loop doWhile="true"> 
 <simple>${header.CamelSqlUpdateCount} != 0</simple> 
  <to uri="sql:{{export.table.b.last.fetched.id.query}}?dataSource=customerDataSource&amp;outputType=SelectOne" />
 <setHeader headerName="last_fetched_id">
  <simple>${body}</simple>
  </setHeader>
  <to uri="sql:{{export.table.a.insert.fetch.query}}?dataSource=customerDataSource" />      
</loop>_

Comment: Like  I said in my answer `<setHeader headerName="last_fetched_id"> <simple>${body}</simple> </setHeader>` is incorrect as sql-component returns either null  or list of maps. You'll have to somehow figure out the `last_fetched_id` yourself. Perhaps by using some sort of index you can increment with CamelSqlRowCount each loop.